# Is such usage of negation acceptable in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage, slang, conversation

Let's begin with a sentence such as:

> We **can't** do this **any** more.

This is the most standard form and grammatically perfect. But I have also seen or heard many times in some informal occasions (maybe that is a fad), esp. in pop lyrics, some sentences like this one

> We **can't** do this **no** more

or even

> **Ain't** got **no** money in my pocket

I'm most aware that such a "fad" is grammatically incorrect and definitely unacceptable in formal occasions. But, what about using it in some informal occasions like everyday conversations? Would that be acceptable? and, since I'm not a native speaker, I want to ask: would such usage (in informal occasions of course) make me appear less "alien" to those native speakers? Or,is it that I better not use it in any case? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: In the 1980s, Ronald Reagan used "You ain't seen nothin' yet" so often—both on the campaign trail and as President—that it turned into a sort of personal catch-phrase. People who liked him thought it was disarmingly droll and informally charming.

Comment: And then there were the rest of us...

Comment: I could never make out whether it was a promise or a threat.

Comment: Have you checked previous posts here and other online resources for the "double negative?" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative

Comment: As for "Is such usage of negation acceptable in everyday conversation?" it's a matter of opinion and so maybe OT here.

Comment: My advice would be not to try and use vernacular that you aren't completely familiar with.  For example using *ain't got* and *can't do this no more* may come off as condescending or offensive in the wrong company. (People may think, "Is he making fun of me?")  Don't try to be someone you're not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you provided. Well maybe I better just follow the standard. And, from the wiki link, such double negative usage seems much more common than I thought, quite interesting!